# Given that the support function $\sigma_S(x)$ is finite-valued, prove that $S$ must be bounded (without the use of Uniform Boundedness Principle)

Tags: functional-analysis

Here is the problem:

Let $S\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ and consider the support function $\sigma_S:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n\cup\{\pm\infty\}$ defined by

$$\sigma_S(x)=\sup_{s\in S}(sx)$$

Prove, without invoking the Uniform Boundedness Principle, that if $\sigma_S$ is finite-valued then $S$ is bounded. (Remember that the unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is compact)

---

Here is what I have. Input would be appreciated:

Given that $|\sigma_S(x)|\lt\infty,\forall x\in\mathbb{R}^n$, let us assume that $S$ is unbounded, that is to say given $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ there does not exist an $r>0$ such that $d(x,s)<r,\forall s\in S$, where $d(x,s)$ is the usual metric on $\mathbb{R}^n$. As $S$ is unbounded, then there is a sequence $s_n\in S$ such that $s_n\to\infty$. Now, let 
$$\sigma_{S_n}(x)=\sup_{s_n\in S}(s_nx)$$
and it is clear that
$$\sigma_{S_n}(x)\leq\sigma_S(x)$$
Then:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sigma_{S_n}(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sup_{s_n\in S}(s_nx)=\sup_{s_n\in S}(\lim_{n\to\infty}s_nx)=\infty$$
And as $\sigma_{S_n}(x)\leq\sigma_S(x)$, this implies that $\sigma_S(x)=\infty$, which is a contradiction, therefore $S$ must be bounded.